# Accessing manually added files on Google Drive using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Our app uses https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope for adding and listing files. One of our users wants to manually copy all of his files from main folder to app folder and then be able to see those files in our app. Obviously those files won't be listed in response from API cause of the scope we use. Is there any way to make those files 'visible' in our app? I don't want to change the scope to full Drive. In documentation we can read that Drive.File scope allows "View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app". What does "files that you have **opened** (...) with this app" mean?

Comment: Hi ! Could you please try with this scope ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly``` to see if that satisfies what the user is amining to do? This will grant **read only access** to file metadata and content allowing for downloads. Let me know if that works :D

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't want to change the scope. We must still use Drive.File scope.

Comment: Ok I understand. So ```View and manage Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app``` means those files that your app **has created** or those which the user has explicitelly **shared with the app**. So maybe a workaround is to make the user share the files with the app to then be able to use them within the app. Would this fit in your scenario?

Comment: You can for example use [GET](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) method to the user's files which will ask the user to grant permissions to your app.

Comment: GET request requires fileId, but at this point I don't know the identifiers of the files outside app's folder. Is there another way to explicitelly share files with my app?

Comment: And what exactly **"explicitly shared with the app"** means? I tried to google this but didn't find an answer.

Comment: Hi ! An interesting way you can use to let users share or open files with your app is to use the [Drive File Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs), in that link you will find a step by step detailed information about how to implement it. With *explicitly shared with the app* I mean that the user will need to authorise personally the use of that file for the app (in the previous example of the ```GET``` call, an authorization window would come up to the user for authorizing the access of the app to his file). Let me know if the Drive Picker was what you were looking for :D